# How to create a type of all the values that are used in a specific key in an array of objects?

Tags: typescript, types

Say I have this interface:

```
interface OrderPurchase {
  headerName: string;
  minWidth: number;
}
```

and then I have an array of objects:

```
const columns: OrderPurchase[] = [
  {
    headerName: 'ID',   
    minWidth: 78,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Email',
    minWidth: 250,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Name',
    minWidth: 180,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Country',
    minWidth: 80,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Total',
    minWidth: 80,
  }];
```

How do I create type *HeaderName* which can have any of the values used in that key in the array? *HeaderName* would be allowed to be *ID, Email, Name, Country* or *Total* and that's it.

I tried this, but it's only limiting values to *string*:

`type HeaderName = typeof columns[number]['headerName'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `columns` isn't literally a typed object, which means that you have to remove the type of it. But even if you remove the type, the compiler widens the types to their primitives. If you would check the type of the `columns` you would get:

```
type HeaderName = {
    headerName: string;
    minWidth: number;
}[]
```

To prevent the widening we can use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) and to make sure that everything is type-safe we can use the [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) operator.

```
const columns = [
  {
    headerName: 'ID',
    minWidth: 78,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Email',
    minWidth: 250,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Name',
    minWidth: 180,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Country',
    minWidth: 80,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Total',
    minWidth: 80,
  },
] as const satisfies readonly  OrderPurchase[];
```

Note that `readonly` is necessary, since *const assertion* turns everything into read-only.

Testing:

```
//  "ID" | "Email" | "Name" | "Country" | "Total"
type HeaderName = typeof columns[number]['headerName'];
```